# How to add onsubmit to form with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add the following:

```
onsubmit="return processForm(this);
```

to this form id

```
<form id="formbuilder" name="featured_homes" method="post" action="fb/feedback.php">
```

with jquery so that the final result reads as:

```
<form id="formbuilder" name="featured_homes" method="post" action="fb/feedback.php" onsubmit="return processForm(this);">
```

Here is my attempt:

```
$('#formbuilder').onsubmit('return processForm(this);');
```

this is not working, any ideas to adjust?

Answer (score 7):

You actually want to add the attribute? I wouldn't do it, but here is how:

```
$('#formbuilder').attr('onsubmit','return processForm(this);');
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/v64N9/)

**OUTPUT:**

```
<form id="formbuilder" name="featured_homes" method="post" action="fb/feedback.php" onsubmit="return processForm(this);">
```

Here's the equivalent without resorting to inline JS:

```
$('#formbuilder').on('submit', function() {
    return processForm(this);
});
```

Which can also be written as:

```
$('#formbuilder').submit(function() {
    return processForm(this);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You want `submit` not `onsubmit`, or `on.("submit",function() { });`

Comment: Ok, so how would I write out this jquery statement?

Comment: Please read the documentation for `submit`, I unfortunately don't have time to teach you to jQuery

Comment: @SterlingArcher If you're going to ask someone to read the docs and decline to teach jQuery, you might mention that e.g. a search for "jquery submit" has excellent odds of finding the official jQuery documentation for e.g. `submit()` as the top "I feel lucky" Google search result.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `submit()`:

```
$('#formbuilder').submit(function() {
    return processForm(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#formbuilder').on('submit', function() {
    return processForm(this);
}
```

Comment: Since this is not going to be written in source code, but rather processed on submit, how can I check the output?

Comment: throw some `console.log` statements in?

Comment: @Presto just a heads up, this website is for people who are proficient with programming. This is NOT insulting your skill level, it's just a fact. You need to research basic javascript and jQuery or you'll be downvoted a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#formbuilder').submit(function(){
    //do whatever you need
});
```